# How to user explicit injector declaration with $routeProvider's resolve param?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angularjs

[$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) `resolve` parameter can allow for injecting additional dependencies to the controller function. **How to combine it with explicit dependecy injection declaration?**

Ecample:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/tabOne', { templateUrl : 'tabOne.html', controller: TabOne, 
                resolve: {
                  someDependency: SomeDependency.factoryFunction
                }
     });
            
});
```

And then:

```
TabOne.$inject = [ '$scope', 'someFirstService', 'someOtherService' ];
```

As you can see DI declaration above will inject two services to my `TabOne` controller (`someFirstService` and `someOtherService`). Those two work fine, but I want my route to change only after `someDependency` has been resolved and injected to `TabOne` as well. If I simply add `someDependency` to Controller function's arguments list it will fail with DI error.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, does your controller just need to wait until the dependency is resolved prior to being invoked, or does it actually need the resolved value of SomeDependency.factoryFunction ?

It seems as if the case is the latter: you want the resolve value.

In this case, one approach that would work would be to have two TabOne controllers.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/tabOne', { templateUrl : 'tabOne.html', controller: TabOneRouted, 
                resolve: {
                  someDependency: SomeDependency.factoryFunction
                }
     });

});

function TabOne($scope, someFirstService, someOtherService) {
  ... code here ...
}

function TabOneRouted($scope, someFirstService, someOtherService, someDependency) {
    TabOne($scope, someFirstService, someOtherService);
    ... your code dealing with someDependency here ...
  }
```